# Rails 4 Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a Fixnum. -- 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I wanted to insert multiple records but with change in SUBJECT_SCORE . I am passing SUBJECT_SCORE as array but getting the error Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a Fixnum. -- 0

Controller.rb

```
def create
    @student_score = studentScore.new(student_score_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student_score.save
        format.html {  flash[:notice] = 'User successfully created.' and redirect_to action: "index"}

        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student_score }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @student_score.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
      def student_score_params
          params.require(:student_score).permit(:student_ID, :primary_key, :ASSESSMENT_ID, :SCHOOL_ID,:SUBJECT_SCORE, :GRADE_CODE, :CREATED_BY, :UPDATED_BY)
        end
```

Model.rb

```
class StudentScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :Subject_SCORE ,Array
 end
```

how do i fix this such that multiple records are inserted in the row with change in subject score and rest of all the params being the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the line serialize:subject_Score,Array in model and it fixed this issue